# override all-auth user model

Tags: django, django-allauth

Im using django all-auth for my website, and I have created a custom subscription system.
I want to create a method *has_active_subscription* in the User model :

```
def has_active_subscription(self) -> bool:
        subscriptions = self.subscriptions.filter(status__in=["active", "trial"])
        return subscriptions.exists()
```

My idea was to create a custom user model like this :

> class CustomUser(AllAuthUser):

But the issue is that I can't find the default all-auth user model *AllAuthUser* (https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/main/allauth/account/models.py).

Also I would like the table's name in the database to be the same as the default one : *auth_user*.

Can someone please help me? :)